# nodejs path.join ignoring my last parameter of rootDir

Tags: node.js, express, directory, path

I'm trying create root dir and reach that by using

```
require.main.path
```

> Return : C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Nodejs\sec-5

but when i try join this dir by using `path.join` its ignoring the last parameter mean sec-5 folder.

```
path.join(rootDir, "views", "shop.html")
```

> Return : C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Nodejs\views\shop.html

// path.js

```
const path = require("path");
console.log("path.js : 2", require.main.path);
module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.path);
```

// shop.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const rootDir = require("../utils/path");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("shop.js : 7", path.join(rootDir, "views", "shop.html"));
  res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, "views", "shop.html"));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Lastly this is my codebase [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all your code is inside `C:\user\HP\Desktop\Nodejs\sec-5` which means the path to your HTML file should be `C:\user\HP\Desktop\Nodejs\sec-5\views\shop.html`, that's why it can't find your HTML file. A simple solution should be in path.js file, export the dirname

```
const path = require("path");
console.log("path.js : 2", require.main.path);
module.exports = require.main.path;
```

Comment: okay working, seems like problem is not path.join ist about path.dirname i checked doc for path.dirname and i gotcha now thaks for help